# Use colormaps along with matplotlib cycler

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to use the matplotlib cycler with colors from palettable.

cycler looks like this:

```
from cycler import cycler
plt.rc('axes', prop_cycle=(cycler('color', ['r', 'g', 'b', 'y']) +
                           cycler('linestyle', ['-', '--', ':', '-.'])))
```

How do I replace the color list above with the color map I obtain from palettable?

```
import palettable
cmap = palettable.colorbrewer.diverging.PRGn_11.mpl_colormap
```

For the answer, it is not critical to use palettable, but it is important to know how to use a colormap.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`cycler` needs an iterable to be assigned to `'colors'`.

Here is a way you could generate one:

```
[plt.get_cmap('jet')(1. * i/n) for i in range(n)]
```

So from your original example:

```
plt.rc('axes', prop_cycle=(cycler('color', ['r', 'g', 'b', 'y']) +
                           cycler('linestyle', ['-', '--', ':', '-.'])))

x = [1,2,3,4]
for i in range(4):
    plt.plot([_ + i for _ in x])
```

[image]

To the modified list from 'jet' colormap:

```
n = 4 # Number of colors
new_colors = [plt.get_cmap('jet')(1. * i/n) for i in range(n)]

plt.rc('axes', 
       prop_cycle=(cycler('color', new_colors) + 
                   cycler('linestyle', ['-', '--', ':', '-.'])))

for i in range(4):
    plt.plot([_ + i for _ in x])
```

[image]

Comment: In your modified example code, the definition of the list `x` is missing.